# Python implementation of Breadth-First Search on Binary Search Trees

Tags: python

I am trying to write a BFS algorithm for a Binary Search Tree using Python3.

I first initialised the class, defined an insert method, and inserted some random numbers:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self, data):
        if data <= self.data:
            if self.left == None:
                self.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.insert(data)
        else:
            if self.right == None:
                self.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.right.insert(data)

root = Node(1)
root.insert(0)
root.insert(2)
root.insert(1.5)
root.insert(2.4)
root.insert(1.6)
root.insert(2.3)
```

Then, I tried to write a recursive BFS method:

```
    def inLineTraversal(self, queue=[]):
        if queue == []:   # Base condition
            return
        temp = queue
        for node in temp:
            print(node.data) 
            if node.left != None:
                queue.append(node.left)
            if node.right != None:
                queue.append(node.right)
            queue.pop(0)
        self.inLineTraversal(queue)
```

However, this produced `1,2,2.4,1.5,2.3,2.3,1.6` as opposed to the correct result of `1,0,2,1.5,2.4,1.6,2.3`.

I later used a while loop to perform the BFS, which correctly produced `1,0,2,1.5,2.4,1.6,2.3`:

```
    def inLineTraversal(self):
        queue = [self]
        while queue != []:
            s = queue.pop(0)
            print(s.data)
            if s.left != None:
                queue.append(s.left)
            if s.right != None:
                queue.append(s.right)
```

What was wrong with the recursive solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
temp = queue
```

This doesn't create a new copy of `queue`, as you probably expected, it just gives it an additional name `temp` - but both names refer to the same list.

So, further on, you iterate on this list while modifying it, which almost always leads to problems.

Just create a copy of your list, like :

```
temp = queue[:]
```

And everything works fine

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self, data):
        if data <= self.data:
            if self.left == None:
                self.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.insert(data)
        else:
            if self.right == None:
                self.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.right.insert(data)

    def inLineTraversalRecursive(self, queue=[]):
        if queue == []:   # Base condition
            return
        temp = queue[:]
        for node in temp:
            print(node.data) 
            if node.left != None:
                queue.append(node.left)
            if node.right != None:
                queue.append(node.right)
            queue.pop(0)
        self.inLineTraversal(queue)

    def inLineTraversalLoop(self):
        queue = [self]
        while queue != []:
            s = queue.pop(0)
            print(s.data)
            if s.left != None:
                queue.append(s.left)
            if s.right != None:
                queue.append(s.right)

root = Node(1)
root.insert(0)
root.insert(2)
root.insert(1.5)
root.insert(2.4)
root.insert(1.6)
root.insert(2.3)
root.inLineTraversalLoop()
print()
root.inLineTraversalRecursive([root])
```

Output:

```
1
0
2
1.5
2.4
1.6
2.3

1
0
2
1.5
2.4
1.6
2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you put `self.inLineTraversal(queue)` outside the for loop. Also this line `temp = queue` is redundant.
So the correct code for your recursive `inLineTraversal` would be:

```
def inLineTraversal(self, queue=[]):
    if queue == []:   # Base condition
        return
    for node in queue:
        print(node.data) 
        if node.left != None:
            queue.append(node.left)
        if node.right != None:
            queue.append(node.right)
        queue.pop(0)
        self.inLineTraversal(queue) # inside of the for loop
```

I tested and ran this modified method, I got the result you expected: `1,0,2,1.5,2.4,1.6,2.3`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 problems in your code
1.) In the InlineTraversal method, You are copying queue to temp array which is not the correct way for copying elements. You are doing shallow copy here. That means both the lists(Queue and Temp) will point to element in same memory location.

2.) You are removing the elements from list inside for loop. you are iterating over Temp list and removing element from queue list which are actually same lists. So, basically you are removing element from same list on which you are iterating which is not a good practice.

To Fix this, perform deep copy on queue list by using

```
temp = queue[:]
```